# result not selected from subquery

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table, I execute this query expecting to get `201705`.

```
SELECT top 1 TIME FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 3 TIME
    FROM TABLE
    WHERE TIME >= 201703
) t
Order by TIME desc
```

However, I get 201712..

```
TIME
201605
201606
201607
201608
201609
201610
201611
201612
201701
201702
201703
201704
201705
201706
201707
201708
201709
201710
201711
201712
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using, that query is product specific.

Comment: Put the order by into the sub query.

Comment: Add  some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text (not images.)

Comment: If 201712 isn't the result you want , what is the expected result?

Comment: I want to get 201705. I want to know why I don't get result from the subquery. I know how to get my result by using two order by or row_number(), however have no idea with this query

Comment: Why don't you follow the advice of @Sankar Raj ? That is the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a subquery, but whenever you use TOP(n) you also need to use ORDER BY

```
SELECT TOP(1) [TIME]
FROM TABLE
WHERE [TIME] >= 201703
ORDER BY [TIME] DESC
```

"time" is a word used in T-SQL (as a data type) so use [] or "" to ensure it isn't misunderstood. I don't recommend "date" or "time" as column names.

If it is the third most recent entry that is wanted, try this

```
SELECT TOP (1) [TIME]
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (3) [TIME]
    FROM TABLE
    WHERE TIME >= 201703
    ORDER BY [TIME] DESC
) t
ORDER BY [TIME] ASC
```

Comment: @TriV Well without the clarity of the op informing us of that it's a guess. Perhaps you are right.

Comment: Yeah, I want to get the third one 201705.